# crud update me muestra pagina en blanco

Tags: html, css, laravel

tengo un problema con el crud, resulta que me muestra la pagina en blanco al terminar una edicionde la tabla.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)

{

    $car = Car::firstOrFail($id);

    $car->patente = $request('patente');

    $car->marca = $request('marca');

    $car->modeo = $request('modelo');

    $car->color = $request('color');

    $car->fecha_ingreso = ('fecha_ingreso');

    $car->save();

    return redirect::back ();

}
```

Y una pequeña muestra del edit.blade.php

```
<div class="container col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <div class="well well bs-component">

            <form method="PUT" action= "{{ route('cars.update', $car->id) }}">
               @csrf

               <div class="row form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <label for="">Patente:</label>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="patente" size="6" maxlength="6" value="{{ $car->patente}}" required>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: uso la versión  5.8.19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los navegadores solo suelen permitir llamadas GET y POST, para mandar un PUT tienes que hacer un POST y mandar una variable en el form llamada "_method" con el valor "PUT".

```
  <form method="POST" action= "{{ route('cars.update', $car->id) }}">
           @csrf
           @method('PUT')
           <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="">Patente:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="patente" size="6" maxlength="6" value="{{ $car->patente}}" required>
                    </div>
           </div>
   </form>
```

Uso un helper de blade para crear un input con los valores comentados anteriormente, igual que has hecho con el @csrf.

Comment: realice lo que me dijo pero ahora me sale el siguiente error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'field list' (SQL: select `1` from `cars` limit 1)"

Comment: @FranciscoGonzálezMejías para encontrar un coche con un id dado, es Car::findOrFail($id) , no Car::firstOrFail().

Comment: ahora me aparece un error "Function name must be a string", sabes como podria ingresar el string en el siguiente: $car->patente = $request('patente');

Comment: @FranciscoGonzálezMejías prueba con $car->patente = $request->patente;

Comment: muchas gracias. pude resolver el problema gracias a sus ayudas.